# Firebase date range between two dates

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to get all "par***" data sets where two dates are between "from" and "to" (x is greater than "from" and y is less than "to").

My Firebase structure is:

[image: Firebase Structure]

I'm using android with java and firebase realtime database.